# Custom directive using ngModelController not updating UI value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that formats a decimal value to a time value `h:mm`. If a user enters a time value the model should be updated with the decimal representation. If a user enters a decimal value his input should be replaced with the formatted value.

I am using the directive as follows:

```
<input type="text" hour-input ng-model="vm.hours"/>
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
app.directive('hourInput', hourInput);

function hourInput() {
  var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel'
  };

  return directive;

  function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
    // model -> view
    ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (value) {
      return formatTime(value);
    });

    // view -> model
    ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (value) {
      var result;
      if (!/^\d?[\d,\.]*$/.test(value)) {
        result = parseTime(value);
      } else {
        result = parseFloat(value);
      }
      return result;
    });
  }
}

function parseTime(value) {
  // code removed for brevity
  return hours + minutes / 60;
}

function formatTime(value) {
  // code removed for brevity
  return result;
}
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0zUiZJhcjFrlcjAVnCo3). The interaction with the model is working. However the formatted time is not updated in the UI.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code into your question instead of just providing a plunker link. That way your question stays valid even if the plunker link is dead

Comment: After updating the value in the controller, have you tried calling scope.$apply(); ? Im no Angular wizard, but I found that to work for me when updating values in a directive and the results not updating in the UI.

Comment: @LouisLewis where in the code would that `$apply` go?

Comment: Can I suggest this link for a possible better explanation than I could offer. http://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html

Comment: You will see he is using setViewValue() and calling render(), I believe that render and apply eventually both will cause a digest to occur, which would update the value. As I said, I am no Angular wizard, just going from what I have battled with.

Comment: @LouisLewis as the blog mentions: "make sure you do not create an infinite loop". Setting the viewValue in the parser does not seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngModelController.$parsers` parses your value with every keystroke. Since you do not know when the user is ready with entering the value, you can't really parse the value on every update.
Assuming you want to allow the values

- 5
- 5.
- 5.5
- 5:30

the parser is not the way you want to go. 
I think that when you attach the function on the blur or change event you get the desired behavior.

Something like

```
element.bind('blur', function () {
      element.val(formatTime(element.val()));
    });
```